# Is there an elegant way to chain (flatten) arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I mean like [python's chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

**Goal**

```
chain([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i']]);
["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]
```

**Actually used but unpleasant solution**

```
function chain($array_of_arrays)
{
    return call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array_of_arrays);
}
```

I'm actually not a big fan of `call_user_func_array` nor `foreach`, so I'm stuck here.

Comment: how about using array_push? see here 

http://armantutorial.wordpress.com/2014/07/02/php-turning-multidimensional-arrays-to-single-dimension-arrays/

Comment: @rm_beginners Wouldn't array_push require a foreach considering the given input anyway ?

Comment: array_push would consider TWO foreach )o:

Comment: So to reiterate, you dislike a language construct intended to allow you to perform iterations, you dislike the solution you've presented that works.. Am I missing something or do we code purely so we can brag how beautiful our code is based on hipster standards or what? If it happens that PHP is really rubbing you the wrong way, I'd consider swapping to Python completely and simply ignoring PHP as a language. A programmer should be able to turn "ugly" solutions into beautiful ones (beautiful being arbitrary here).

Comment: @N.B. : i think you are thinking way too much!! OP only wants an *equivalent* solution / method ...calm down!! :)

Comment: I'm a C and Python dev, and today I have to write "some" PHP, I'm only trying to do my best so my code stay readable (Putting my call_user_func_array in an explicitly named function is a good start point, instead of writing it inline, it may be enough to keep me in peace.)

Comment: @luvieere Not a duplicate, I'm not trying to group values under common keys.

Comment: `$result = array_merge($first_array, $second_array, $third_array.... $nth_array);`. Alternatively you can create a variadic function `chain` that simply returns result of `array_merge`.

Comment: @N.B.: I does not have my arrays in separated variables but in an array (actually the result of an array_map). And I don't know how many I have.

Comment: @ulien Parad I thought you are using multi-dimentional array.

Comment: If you're using php >= 5.5.0, you could basically use the exact same function as in python. demo: http://3v4l.org/mUDjV

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
function chain($array_of_arrays)
{
    return array_reduce($array_of_arrays,'array_merge',array());
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just a worse version than what the question already shows?

Comment: @Jon Well, it's a matter of opinion whether it's worse or not... OP asked for an alternative solution and there it is... If you think you have a better one, you can post it... :)

Comment: @clami : i don't downvote answers, so *assume* i did -1 on this, its not about *alternative solution* but about *better alternative solution*!! :)

Comment: I used "worse" in the sense that it's very close to the original and yet involves an additional function (`array_reduce`) that's not really required. Does more work to get the same result with no added value.

Comment: @NoobEditor Thanks, it's nice of you :) But still, I don't understand what's the problem with this answer... of course, it uses a method that is very similar to the one proposed by OP, but it uses a different logic... and the real point is that OP doesn't like to call call_user_func_array (I don't know why) or foreach loops, so I proposed a function that doesn't use either... that's it! If you can do better, again, post your answer and I'll upvote you! :)

Comment: @clami219 : i don't know a better answer, so didn't posted...but i know this is *not* a better answer so commented!! ;)

Comment: @NoobEditor Fair enough! It's your right to do so, isn't it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 3-liner without `call_user_func_array` and `foreach`:

```
function chain($array)
{
    $return = [];

    array_walk_recursive($array, function($x) use (&$return) { $return[] = $x; });

    return $return;
}
```

That's actually [how Laravel does it](http://laravel.com/api/source-function-array_flatten.html#179-192).

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i']];

function test_call($input)
{
    return call_user_func_array('array_merge', $input);
}

function test_foreach($input)
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($input as $array) {
        foreach ($array as $value) {
            $result[$value] = true;
        }
    }

    return array_keys($result);
}

function test_reduce($input)
{
    return array_reduce($input, 'array_merge', []);
}

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1e5; ++$i) {
    test_call($input);
}
var_dump(microtime(true) - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1e5; ++$i) {
    test_foreach($input);
}
var_dump(microtime(true) - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1e5; ++$i) {
    test_reduce($input);
}
var_dump(microtime(true) - $start);
```

RESULTS

call_user_func_array - double(0.56941080093384)
foreach - double(0.70889902114868)
array_reduce - double(0.76243710517883)

Comment: The problem is that I don't have my arrays in separate variables but in an array, and I don't know how many I have.

Comment: Results of thins kind of test may be dependent of the number of arrays AND the number of values in each of them. Also I'm not searching for a fast solution, those times are neglictibles, I was searching for a readable/elegant one.